# Python remove temporary files using MVC framework

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, wxpython, temporary-files

I am writing a Python program, with GUI (wxPython). This program interacts with a RPC server. I would like to create temporary files from the GUI, which can be read by the RPC server, on Windows.

The tempfile module does not seem to satisfy my needs. I want to write to the tempfile, close it (so the RPC server can read it, here Windows differs from Unix), and only when the program ends (or for example the Model (Model-View-...) is destroyed) remove the tempfile from the file system.

Because of the (GUI) structure of my program, I don't exactly see where to insert any try: finally block, unless right after **__*main*__**. But then I can't bind the tempfiles to the model?

Should I touch the **__*del*__** method of the model? And how then exactly? Everywhere, I read not to touch this method...

Thanks

Regarding the RPC Server: This is closed software which I cannot modify.

Comment: Why not just interact with the RPC server directly?

Answer (score 0):

I would create some kind of variable that holds the path to your temp file. Something like this:

```
self.myTempFile = /path/to/temp.txt
```

Then bind the frame to wx.EVT_CLOSE:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)
```

In your onClose method, you will attempt to delete the temp file and then you will call the frame's Destroy() method. You cannot call its Close method as that will just call onClose recursively.